# POP is enabled from 2006, want to have it marked enabled from 2005

Tags: gmail, pop3

I have been using Gmail since mid 2005 and didn't realize that I had to activate POP manually. So my POP access is enabled only from 2006 November. With the recent outages, I want to backup using POP and not IMAP cause that doesn't do much anyway.

Is there anyway I could get Google to reset my POP Access enabled date to 2005 from 2006? I know it sounds crazy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to backup your Gmail, it's perfectly fine to do it using IMAP.

In Windows, try with [Gmail Backup](http://download.cnet.com/Gmail-Backup/3000-2369_4-10903796.html). In Linux, `offlineimap` is excellent software for that.

As of POP settings, in Gmail->Mail settings->Forwarding and POP/IMAP, you can choose
[image: POP settings]

That should enable access to earlier emails too.

Comment: How do you backup using IMAP btw? I have that setup in Postbox on OSX & whenever anything changes on Gmail's servers, it changes locally.

Comment: Umm, you can download emails using IMAP. If you are not syncing everything after that, it's backed up (and of course, it's common thing to sync backups with current versions).

Comment: Well, yeah of course I can download via another protocol besides POP. But going online anytime after that it would sync up. POP is for the real backup I guess. Thanks though.

Comment: @Abhic: ? You can use IMAP and then zip the folder containing the messages, so you'd have a static backup as you with.